# How can I do memory management in C++ when a class needs to throw out and replace a member object many times during its lifetime?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, memory

I'm writing a C++ application. This is a memory management question, I have a background in scripting languages and am new to C++.

I have a little class representing a GUI view, call it View, and within that view there's a text field and a button. When the user clicks the button, the text field is interpreted as a shell command and the shell command is run. This is managed by a Process class which has methods like `run()`, `getOutput()` and `stop()`. So View contains a reference of some sort to an instance of Process.

Initially my implementation looked like this (not actual code, just a sketch):

```
class View
{
    Process *process;
public:
    onClickExecute()
    {
        process = new Process(command);
        process->run();
    }

    onClickStop()
    {
        process->stop();
    }

    // Called when the process ends, either by the user clicking stop or just by it ending naturally.
    onProcessComplete()
    {
        delete process;
    }

}
```

This worked well, but then I thought: why am I torturing myself by making `process` a pointer? If I just make it by-value, I don't have to worry about deleting it later. This seemed like the more "correct" way to manage memory in this case, so I tried making `process` by value, but then C++ complained that I wasn't initializing it in the constructor! `Process` has no default constructor because a `Process` instance with no command is meaningless. I could *make* it meaningful by providing a dummy constructor and a setter, but that feels like I'm modifying my design just because of language technicalities rather than because it's the design I want. Is there some way I can tell C++ "just fill `process` with garbage uninitialized bytes until I click the button and create an instance"?

The more abstract problem here is: a parent object has a child object. The child object is meaningless when the parent is constructed, it becomes meaningful only later. The child object will need to be tossed and replaced with a "new" instance several times during the lifetime of the parent. How can we manage the memory here in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Try `std::optional`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do want to use pointers because you want to represent an object that can be present or absent, depending on the enclosing object's state. But dealing with raw pointers correctly is very tricky: Raw pointers are prone to bugs, segfaults, use-after-free vulnerabilities, memory leaks, and frequently break if exceptions are involved.

The solution is to use *smart pointers*. These are generally safe to use because the referenced object is automatically deleted when the smart pointer is destroyed, but can still model pointery things like null pointers.

There is `std::optional` which can be used to represent values that are present or absent *without* the overhead of allocating the pointed-to value separately, but it's not necessarily most appropriate here.

Instead: use `std::unique_ptr`. Whenever you think you need to use a pointer, first try using `std::unique_ptr`. Being an unique pointer means that the pointer owns the pointed-to object which allows it to be deleted with zero overhead compared to manual new/delete. If you would have a more complex object graph, then `std::shared_ptr` implements reference-counted pointers.

With an unique pointer, your code would look something like this:

```cpp
class View {
  std::unique_ptr<Process> process;  // is initialized to nullptr
public:
  void onClickExecute() {
    if (process) return;  // what if process is already initialized?
    process = std::make_unique<Process>(command);
    process->run();
  }

  void onClickStop() {
    if (process) process->stop();
  }

  void onProcessComplete() {
    process.reset(nullptr); // will correctly delete if necessary
  }
};
```

Unique pointers became available with C++11, make_unique in C++14 (but it's just a few lines of code to backport it if necessary).

Comment: Just seems odd that I need to change the way things are laid out in memory just because I want to model a field that may or may not be present. It seems like this couples together two things that should be orthogonal. Why couldn't there just be a way of saying "store these bytes where the class instance is stored, but leave them uninitialized until I come in and initialize them"?

Comment: @JackM That's exactly what std::optional does, though it needs an extra bool to know whether the memory is currently initialized or not. If you want to do C-style programming without any safety checks, consider using a `union` with a single member.

Comment: If you don't have `std::optional` or `boost::optional`, you can do it yourself with `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Process), alignof(Process)> storage; Process * process;` and `process = new (storage) Process(command);`, `process->~Process(); process = nullptr;`

Comment: @Caleth: Note that it will not call a destructor.

Comment: @NicolBolas do you mean the default `~View()`? Yes, you'd need to define `View`'s special members (carefully)

Comment: @Caleth Clever. For such a simple situation definitely too clever by about an order of magnitude.

Comment: @besc `aligned_storage_t` is how `boost::optional` defines storage for it's value. I don't have a definition for `Process`, so went with the safe option over guessing `char [sizeof(Process)]` with no alignment qualification.

Comment: @besc and the standard requires `std::optional` to do similar "When an instance of `optional<T>` contains a value, it means that an object of type `T`, referred to as the optional object's contained value, is allocated within the storage of the optional object. Implementations are not permitted to use additional storage, such as dynamic memory, to allocate its contained value. The contained value shall be allocated in a region of the `optional<T>` storage suitably aligned for the type `T`. "

Comment: @Caleth That’s true. But std::optional hides all those nitty gritty low-level details, and that’s the point. There are a lot of simple options available. At least: smart pointered heap allocation like in amon’s answer, one of the optional types, making Process default constructible. Because of that I wouldn’t consider manual usage of aligned_storage as a viable solution unless there are rock solid reasons why none of the alternatives is useable here.

Comment: @besc "If you **don't have** `std::optional` or `boost::optional`, you can **do it yourself**"

Comment: @Caleth Maybe I could have phrased my previous comment clearer. What I mean is, even if you don’t have access to an optional type, going for aligned storage and rolling your own isn’t a great approach here because there are other simpler solutions that almost certainly do an adequate job.